# How can I get information about all database sessions that have unclosed transactions?

Tags: oracle

How using information from the data dictionary views, to obtain information about all database sessions in which there are unclosed transactions?
Do I need to use DBA_2PC_NEIGHBORS and DBA_WAITERS?

Answer (score 2):

No you don't. There is a view in Oracle to display active transactions. All you need is to join it with v$session

```
SELECT s.sid
  FROM v$transaction t
 INNER JOIN v$session s ON t.addr = s.taddr;
```

UPD: [link](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/server.920/a96524/c05dicti.htm) to data dictionary definition

Comment: Then the question is.
v$transaction and other dynamic views relate to the data dictionary?

Comment: @user376237 I think it is. Oracle says data dictionary contains also "Other general database information" so transactions and sessions are part of it.

Comment: "Then the question is. v$transaction and other dynamic views relate to the data dictionary".  Suppose that by some hair-splitting definition they are not considered part of (related to) the data dictionary?  What do you then do differently, given that the dynamic views shown actually provide the desired information about the database?